# Url pattern mapping at webapp2 (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, webapp2

I have strange feelings about **webapp2** routing and thats why,
in example below there is a sneek peek from news mapping on my site.

And the question is, why in some keys **strict_slash=True** works well and (generates 301) and in another wont work at all (404)?

```
from webapp2 import WSGIApplication, Route as url
from webapp2_extras.routes import (PathPrefixRoute as patterns, 
                                   RedirectRoute as rurl)

from .views import (MainHandler)
from .views_news import (NewsAllHandler, NewsAnnualHandler, NewsMonthlyHandler, 
                         NewsDailyHandler, NewsTagsHandler, NewsTagHandler, 
                         NewsHandler)

app = WSGIApplication([
    url('/', MainHandler, 'main'),
    patterns('/news', [
        rurl('/', NewsAllHandler, 'news_all', 
             strict_slash=True), # here wont work /news isn't /news/ — get 404
        patterns('/tags', [
            rurl('/', NewsTagsHandler, 'news_tags', 
                 strict_slash=True), # works well /tags 301 redirects to /tags/
            rurl('/<tag:[\w\d-]+>/', NewsTagHandler, 'news_tag', 
                 strict_slash=True),
        ]),
        patterns('/<year:\d{4}>', [
            rurl('/', NewsAnnualHandler, 'news_year', 
                 strict_slash=True), # works well /d{4} 301 redirects to /d{4}/
            rurl('/<month:\d{2}>/', NewsMonthlyHandler, 'news_month', 
                 strict_slash=True),
            rurl('/<month:\d{2}>/<day:\d{2}>/', NewsDailyHandler, 'news_day', 
                 strict_slash=True),
            rurl('/<month:\d{2}>/<day:\d{2}>/<slug:[\w\d-]+>/', NewsHandler, 'news', 
                 strict_slash=True),
        ]),
    ]),
], debug=True)
```

Have I miss something?
Please, help me, it's freaking me out!

Comment: If there's a 500 error, there will be a message in the log explaining it.

Comment: Greg, I beg you a pardon, 404 not 500, of course.
So nothing more than this INFO 2013-07-01 21:02:54,762 server.py:593] default: "GET /news HTTP/1.1" 404 154

Comment: The only difference I see is news only has one non-prefixed pattern, try adding a random rurl and see if it works, then it could be a bug and you can report it if it works that way.

Comment: Faisal, nope it doesn't work. For now i use this: rurl('/news', redirect_to_name='news_all') for correct mapping. But it's f$*&#@ odd!

Comment: In _debug_ mode I find out that url match looking for regexp `^\\/news(?P<__0__>/.*)$` and within `/news` couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

So by now I use **RedirectRoute** after `patterns('/news', […])` to map from `/news` to `/news/`.

```
rurl('/news', redirect_to='/news/'),
```